# Connect to SQL Server local database

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm writing a macro in Microsoft Excel that makes an update in a table of my local SQL Server database,.

My connection string:

```
sConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Scrape;"
```

I get this error:

> Data source name not found and no default driver specific

How do I write the connection string?

Comment: Have you tried recording an macro in excel and than connecting to your database while macro is recording?. If you are successful on doing that , you will be able to answer your own question.

Comment: I would recommend trying these steps: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Whenever I need to figure out a connection string I go [to this site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should be pretty simple.  See the link below.

https://www.erpsoftwareblog.com/2017/01/microsoft-excel-connections-sql-databases/

Also, check this out.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Finally, to update a SQL Server table with Excel/VBA code, do the following.

```
Sub UpdateMyTable()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String
Dim rngName As Range
Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=MyServer; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=MyDB;" & _
            "User ID=User;" & _
            "Password=Pwd;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=No"
    Set rngName = ActiveCell
cnn.Open cnnstr
uSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET Field = 1 WHERE Field = ' " & rngName & " ' "
'Debug.Print (uSQL)
cnn.Execute uSQL
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Post back, with specific details, if you have issues with this code.  Thanks.